# scheduling embedded python processes

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, scheduler

I've been trying to create a C++ program that embeds multiple python threads. Due to the nature of the program the advantage of multitasking comes from asynchronous I/O; but due to some variables that need to be altered between context switching I need to control the scheduling.  I thought that because of python's GIL lock this would be simple enough, but it's turning out not to be: python wants to use POSIX threads rather than software threads, I can't figure out from the documentation what happens if I store the result of `PyEval_SaveThread()` and don't call `PyEval_RestoreThread()` in the same function--so presumably I'm not supposed to be doing that, etc.

Is it possible to create a custom scheduler for embedded python threads, or was python basically designed so that it can't be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that using `PyEval_SaveThread()` and `PyEval_RestoreThread()` is unnecessary, basically I used coroutines to run the scripts and control the scheduling.  In this case from [libPCL](http://www.xmailserver.org/libpcl.html).  However this isn't really much of a solution because if python encounters a syntax error it will segfault if it is in a coroutine, oddly enough even if there is only one python script running in one coroutine this will still happen. But at the very least they don't seem to conflict with each other.